# Are Log Predictive Likelihood, Log Predictive Probability, Log Marginal Likelihood and Log Predictive Density same?

Tags: bayesian, terminology, model-comparison, scoring-rules

I have seen different papers use different terms to express the scoring rules that they used to compare Bayesian models. Some of those terms are,

- Log Predictive Density (Bayesian Data Analysis - by Andrew Gelman)
- [Log Predictive Likelihood](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v33/ranganath14.pdf)
- [Log Predictive Probability](http://www.columbia.edu/~jwp2128/Papers/HoffmanBleiWangPaisley2013.pdf)
- [Log Marginal Likelihood](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5593-distributed-variational-inference-in-sparse-gaussian-process-regression-and-latent-variable-models)

In the book "Bayesian Data Analysis" by A. Gelman, it is explained that log predictive density is used to compare Bayesian models. However, the papers that I have read uses different metrics (or different words to describe the same metrics). My questions are,

1. Are all these terms denotes the same scoring rule? if not can you please explain me the difference of each of them compared to the 1st one(log predictive density)
2. Which one of them is most suitable to compare Bayesian regression models? Or are there any better scoring rule?

I appreciate any help to understand above terms.